# How to fix the shadows in armor stands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image]

When I drop a TNT and it touches the ground, it summons an armor stand but they look black like those in the picture, which is obviously not the desired result.

How do I make the TNT not have the black shadow above it?

The commands are :

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] ITEM 1 {OnGround:1b,Item:{id:minecraft:tnt,tag:{display:{Name:Explosion Barrel}}}}

/execute @e[score_ITEM_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon armor_stand ~ ~-0.7 ~ {CustomName:"Dinamita",NoGravity:1b,ShowArms:1,Small:1,Marker:1b,Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1,Rotation:[20f,0.0f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:tnt,Count:1b}],ArmorDropChances:[0.085F,0.085F,0.085F,0.0F]}

/kill @e[type=Item] {Item:{id:"minecraft:tnt",tag:{display:{Name:Explosion Barrel}}}} (This is for kill the first item)
```

I fixed it!.

I was using little armor stand so i changed them for a normal and ready! (1.11.2v)

Comment: it would be good to know what exactely your summon command looks like, so we can help you debugging the problem.

Comment: Okay, i already put the commands in my question

Comment: You should still leave the question up for anyone else who has the same question as you AtodoH.

Comment: yeah... sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be happening because the tnt is in the ground maybe try summoning it higher

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the armorstands is that their "focus point" (and thus the point that checks wether it's inside a block) is in different places, depending on the circumstances.

- **normal sized, non-marker** armorstands do have their focus point on their head
- **normal sized, marker** armorstands do have their focus point at the very bottom
- **small sized, non-marker** armorstands do have their focus point in the middle of their body
- **small sized, marker** armorstands do have their focus point at the very bottom

[See this picture for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRnDp.jpg)

---

So, to solve your problem you'd have to make sure the armorstands focus point is not inside a solid block.
Of course, you could just change every possible place this thing can be into a transparent block, but this is obviously not a good solution.
It is kinda achieveable by putting the TnT into the armorstands hand instead of his head and change the hand pose slightly, like this:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~0.2 ~ {NoGravity:1b,ShowArms:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:"tnt",Count:1b},{}],Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]},Small:1}
```

This method requires you to make the armorstands non-marker, which could lead to some problems with projectiles, if you're using those. If you can use this or not depends on what needs to be happening in your map.
If this doesn't work for you, i hope you at least understand what you might be able to do and come up with a solution yourself.